# Focus Around Multiple Cells In ag-Grid (Like Clicking and Dragging Mouse In Excel)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I would like to be able to click and drag the mouse to expand/shape the cells that I want the focus box around. In Excel this is a very useful feature and I was hoping ag-Grid had something similar. Please let me know if you know if ag-Grid supports this and/or if you have any ideas on how to do it yourself.

I have spent a while searching around and can't seem to find anything about changing the size of the focus box.

Here is a link to a picture of an Excel spreadsheet with an expanded focus box: [excel_spreadsheet](https://www.accountingweb.com/sites/default/files/Name-Box-Figure-2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but I think you are looking for Range Selection:

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
};
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!